# Spring cloud stream what is the meaning of in-0

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

I have see this config of spring cloud stream

```
spring:
  cloud:
    function:
      definition: topic1
    stream:
      bindings:
        topic1-in-0:
          destination: topic1
          group: topic1
```

Could you guys explain me what is `-0` at the end of bindings? Can we have `-1`, `-10`, ..., `-100`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can have multiple suffixes `-1`, `-2`, etc but you won't need it often.

It's called partial function chaining or currying and you can read more about it at Spring Cloud reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_beyond_two_inputs

Comment: Primary reason is to support function with multiple inputs and outputs, hence 0 signifies the index of such in or out which as pointed out by Nikolai is what is mostly used - https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_functions_with_multiple_input_and_output_arguments